# 'Session' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, neo4j

I am receiving an error

[image]

this is my code block (simplified, but still demonstrates error)

```
import neo4j
import sys
import uuid

from neo4j import GraphDatabase


def create_population_point(tx, _point, _uuid, _tl, _tr, _ll, _lr, _band):
    print("Add a record block  A")
    tx.run("CREATE (n:Population_Point 
    {point:$point,uuid:$uuid,TL:$tl,TR:$tr,BL:$bl,BR:$br,Band_1:$band}),"
          "point=_point,uuid=_uuid,tl=_tl,tr=_tr,ll=_ll,lr=_lr,band=_band")


def main():
uri = "neo4j://localhost:7687"
username = "neo4j"
password = "P@ssword2"

databaseConnection = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(username, password))
databaseSession = databaseConnection.session()
print("Connection established")
print("Variables assigned values")
_point = "D007_S001_T001"
_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
_tl = "28.27291"
_tr = "-81.65765"
_ll = "28.27291"
_lr = "-81.65765"
_band = "455"
print("Ready to execute")
with databaseSession.session() as session:
    result = session.write_transaction(create_population_point, _point, _uuid, _tl, _tr, _ll, 
   _lr, _band)
databaseConnection.close()
print("Connection closed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the line that is throwing the error

with databaseSession.session() as session:

running python 3.10.4

Comment: I don't know the context of what you want, but seems like you can change this line: ```with databaseSession.session() as session:``` to ```with databaseConnection.session() as session:```

Comment: After looking through the doc, appears I'm right.  You are calling ```session()``` twice

Comment: first you create `databaseSession = databaseConnection.session()` next you use `with databaseSession.session() as session:` so finally you try to use `databaseConnection.session().session()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create

```
databaseSession = databaseConnection.session()
```

next you use

```
with databaseSession.session() as session:
```

so finally you try to use

```
databaseConnection.session().session()
```

and this is wrong.

You could use directly

```
result = databaseSession.write_transaction(..)
```

or use `databaseConnection` instead of `databaseSession` in

```
with databaseConnection.session() as session:
     result = session.write_transaction(..)
```

(and remove `databaseSession = databaseConnection.session()` because you don't use it)